# How to download our Google Web History?

Tags: google-search

In [Google Web History](https://history.google.com/history/), I can view all my past web searches.

How can I download this data, instead of viewing them page by page on the website?

Comment: Related: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/67319/how-do-i-export-my-google-search-history

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google offers the ability to download your search history through Google Takeout.

1. Visit the [Download your data](https://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout) page. You might have to sign in to your Google Account.
2. Choose which Google products to include in your download. Obviously you'll want search, but you can choose whatever other products' data you want to download.
3. Select Next.
4. Choose your archive's "File type."

([Google Support](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3024190))

Comment: It seems to be gone now.

Comment: @Flash: I've updated with new instructions.