# How do I export my Google search history?

Tags: google-search, export

I'd like to export all of my search history into one file. This used to be easy, but apparently something changed in 2012 or so that the old way of doing stuff (as seen in http://geeklad.com/download-google-history) doesn't work any more.

Comment: Duplicate of http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/46636/10579

Answer (score 0):

Google now offers the ability to download your search history.

> First, visit history.google.com/history when you're logged in to your
>   account. Then look for the options icon, and click download.
>
> You'll be prompted to create an archive, and your history will begin
>   downloading — it's as simple as that. The archive will be saved to
>   your Google Drive in the form of a zip file that can be saved to your
>   desktop computer.
>
> Of course, you'll need to have your search history option turned on
>   for the feature to work. If you've opted out of keeping a record of
>   your search history, you'll find nothing available.

([source](http://mashable.com/2015/04/20/google-search-history/))
([Google Support](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/6068625?p=ws_history_download&rd=1))

Answer (score -1):

It should be available in your data tools, but I can't confirm because I don't track history.

Account - data tools - download data

[goggles](https://www.google.com/settings/takeout/custom/goggles)

Comment: Nope, data tools doesn't support search history exports.