# Downloaded Google Search history, JSON file, unreadable

Tags: google-search-history

I downloaded my Google Search history. It's a JSON file. I loaded a Dropbox link to the file into an [online JSON viewer](http://codebeautify.org/jsontoxml).  That gave me some XML.  I don't know how to convert the time stamps.  For example, apparently "1444936291238326" is the same as 3:11 pm.

What's an easy way of getting a *readable* search history?

Related: [How to download our Google Web History?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/46636/how-to-download-our-google-web-history)

Comment: I asked this question because it seems as though when I did a copy and paste of the list of searches, the times were not being copied, but today I tried again, and the highlight-and-copy operation *did* pick up the times.  So I no longer need to do the google download.

Comment: It sounds as if you no longer have an issue. If so, feel free to either flag your question for closure or delete it, unless you believe that an answer to your original question would benefit the masses.

Comment: @SightSpirit - I hope you don't mind if we wait a little longer.  I'm still curious if I was doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I *suspect* `1444936291238326` should be parsed: `1444936291` and `238326` with the former the Unix timestamp for not just time of day but day too: October 15, 2015 @ 7:11pm (UTC).

At this time of year most of Indiana is GMT-5, so 7:11pm UTC not far off 3:11pm local there.

`238326` might be for seconds.